# Performance tuning using NOT EXISTS in Teradata

Tags: performance, query-optimization, teradata, not-exists, teradatasql

IE_VT is a volatile table that is created with UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( STORE_NUMBER, UPC, POS_DEPT, POS_DEPT_NUMBER )

Now our code tries to insert into the VT by selecting few columns from various tables.

ACTUAL QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO IE_VT 
       (STORE_NUMBER,
        UPC,
        SKU_REGIONAL,
        REGION,
        ITEM_LONG_DESCRIPTION,
        POS_DESCRIPTION,
        POS_DEPT,
        POS_DEPT_NUMBER,
        ITEM_SIZE,
        ITEM_SIZE_NUMBER,
        ITEM_UOM,
        BRAND,
        REG_HIER_REF,
        ITEM_STATUS,
        CREATE_DATE,
        COMMODITY_CODE,
        NAT_UPC,
        START_DATE,
        END_DATE,
        LAST_UPDATE)
SELECT  ir.STORE_NUMBER,  
        ir.UPC,                                               
        ir.SKU_REGIONAL,                                      
        ir.REGION,                                            
        ir.ITEM_LONG_DESCRIPTION,                             
        ir.POS_DESCRIPTION, 
        coalesce(otr.POS_DEPT,'00000'),                         -- Set to default POS_DEPT if not found in ORG_TEAM_REF                                    
        a.DEPARTMENT,                                           -- Invalid POS_DEPT, not in hierarchy.  Will be null if not valid integer.                    
               
        ir.ITEM_SIZE,                                         
        ir.ITEM_SIZE_NUMBER,                                  
        ir.ITEM_UOM,                                          
        ir.BRAND,                                             
        ir.REG_HIER_REF,                                      
        ir.ITEM_STATUS,                                                        
                   
        ir.CREATE_DATE,
        ir.COMMODITY_CODE,
        ir.NAT_UPC,
        ir.START_DATE,                                   
        COALESCE(ir.END_DATE, CAST('2999-12-31' AS DATE)) END_DATE,
        ir.LAST_UPDATE
 FROM   
       (
               SELECT distinct  x.STORE_NUMBER, 
                                x.UPC, 
                                x.DEPARTMENT
               FROM             EW.PRD_SCS x
               LEFT OUTER JOIN  EW.ITRM_R y            -- Invalid POS_DEPT_NUMBER in PRD_SALES_COST_SUMMARY.
                   ON  x.STORE_NUMBER =    y.STORE_NUMBER       -- But still valid item per STORE_NUMBER / UPC in IR.
                   AND x.UPC =             y.UPC
                   and x.DEPARTMENT =      y.POS_DEPT_NUMBER 
                   and y.PDN_END_DATE is null
               WHERE y.ITEM_REGION_ID IS NULL
       ) A        
join    EDW.STORE B  
            on  a.STORE_NUMBER = b.STORE_NUMBER
            and b.END_DATE is null  
join    EW.ITRM_R ir                                   -- Item is valid for STORE.
            on  b.REGION =          ir.REGION
            and a.STORE_NUMBER =    ir.STORE_NUMBER
            and a.UPC =             ir.UPC
            and ir.END_DATE is null
LEFT OUTER JOIN                  
        EDW.ORG_TEAM_REF  otr                                -- With possibly still valid POS_DEPT_NUMBER per OTR.
            on  b.REGION =          otr.REGION
            and a.STORE_NUMBER  =   otr.STORE_NUMBER
            and a.DEPARTMENT =      otr.POS_DEPT_NUMBER
            and otr.END_DATE is null -- 2678712 records
--------            
where  (a.STORE_NUMBER, a.UPC, trim(leading '0' from coalesce(otr.POS_DEPT,'00000')), a.department)
            not in  (select STORE_NUMBER,                       -- LOJ to IE_VT is much slower.
                            UPC, 
                            trim(leading '0' from POS_DEPT),
                            POS_DEPT_NUMBER
                     from   IE_VT); -- 2678700 records
```

Our Actual query is working well and pretty fast until the 5 lines above where marked with -------- ONly after that our query is consuming 500K CPU seconds and is running for around 10 mins and gives us the final set of 2678700 records.

There by I tried replacing the where clause with where not exists and below is the altered query.

---

TUNED QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO IE_VT1 
       (STORE_NUMBER,
        UPC,
        SKU_REGIONAL,
        REGION,
        ITEM_LONG_DESCRIPTION,
        POS_DESCRIPTION,
        POS_DEPT,
        POS_DEPT_NUMBER,
        ITEM_SIZE,
        ITEM_SIZE_NUMBER,
        ITEM_UOM,
        BRAND,
        REG_HIER_REF,
        ITEM_STATUS,
        CREATE_DATE,
        COMMODITY_CODE,
        NAT_UPC,
        START_DATE,
        END_DATE,
        LAST_UPDATE)
SELECT  ir.STORE_NUMBER, 
        ir.UPC,                  
        ir.SKU_REGIONAL,                                      
        ir.REGION,                                            
        ir.ITEM_LONG_DESCRIPTION,                             
        ir.POS_DESCRIPTION, 
        coalesce(otr.POS_DEPT,'00000'),                         -- Set to default POS_DEPT if not found in ORG_TEAM_REF                                    
        a.DEPARTMENT,                                           -- Invalid POS_DEPT, not in hierarchy.  Will be null if not valid integer.                    
               
        ir.ITEM_SIZE,                                         
        ir.ITEM_SIZE_NUMBER,                                  
        ir.ITEM_UOM,                                          
        ir.BRAND,                                             
        ir.REG_HIER_REF,                                      
        ir.ITEM_STATUS,                                                        
                   
        ir.CREATE_DATE,
        ir.COMMODITY_CODE,
        ir.NAT_UPC,
        ir.START_DATE,                                   
        COALESCE(ir.END_DATE, CAST('2999-12-31' AS DATE)) END_DATE,
        ir.LAST_UPDATE
 FROM   
       (
               SELECT distinct  x.STORE_NUMBER, 
                                x.UPC, 
                                x.DEPARTMENT
               FROM             EW.PRD_SCS x
               LEFT OUTER JOIN  EW.ITRM_R y            -- Invalid POS_DEPT_NUMBER in PRD_SALES_COST_SUMMARY.
                   ON  x.STORE_NUMBER =    y.STORE_NUMBER       -- But still valid item per STORE_NUMBER / UPC in IR.
                   AND x.UPC =             y.UPC
                   and x.DEPARTMENT =      y.POS_DEPT_NUMBER 
                   and y.PDN_END_DATE is null
               WHERE y.ITEM_REGION_ID IS NULL
       ) A        
join    EDW.STORE B  
            on  a.STORE_NUMBER = b.STORE_NUMBER
            and b.END_DATE is null  
join    EW.ITRM_R ir                                   -- Item is valid for STORE.
            on  b.REGION =          ir.REGION
            and a.STORE_NUMBER =    ir.STORE_NUMBER
            and a.UPC =             ir.UPC
            and ir.END_DATE is null
LEFT OUTER JOIN                  
        EDW.ORG_TEAM_REF  otr                                -- With possibly still valid POS_DEPT_NUMBER per OTR.
            on  b.REGION =          otr.REGION
            and a.STORE_NUMBER  =   otr.STORE_NUMBER
            and a.DEPARTMENT =      otr.POS_DEPT_NUMBER
            and otr.END_DATE is null  --2678712 records
-----------
where not exists
(
select store_number,upc,trim(leading '0' from POS_DEPT) as POS_DEPT,pos_dept_number from IE_VT1 vt
where a.STORE_NUMBER =  vt.store_number
and a.upc = vt.upc
and trim(leading '0' from coalesce(otr.POS_DEPT,'00000')) =  vt.POS_DEPT
and a.department =vt.pos_dept_number);  --2678712 22 Secs
```

The above tuned query is taking only 25K CPU secs, but even after the where not exists clause, the final count is same as what is before the Where not Exists clause "2678712 records".

Can someone please help me here on how to implement where no exists in this query?

Comment: It's not the same conditions, should be `trim(leading '0' from coalesce(otr.POS_DEPT,'00000')) =  Trim(Leading '0' FROM vt.POS_DEPT)`

Comment: I have used that in the select condition in NOT EXISTS subquery `select store_number,upc,trim(leading '0' from POS_DEPT) as POS_DEPT,pos_dept_number `. Is that wrong?

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks. Adding it likewise also `trim(leading '0' from coalesce(otr.POS_DEPT,'00000')) =  Trim(Leading '0' FROM vt.POS_DEPT)` didnt give me any difference, it is still giving me 2678712

Comment: `vt.POS_DEPT` is the base column. And just `POS_DEPT` will still be the base column,  If you want to use the calculated column in WHERE you have to rename it to a different alias.

Comment: @dnoeth Still no luck. Sorry.

Comment: Might be related to NULLs. Btw, as the conditions match the UPI of the target table, you might be able to replace the INSERT/SELECT NOT EXISTS with a MERGE using  WHEN NOT MATCHED only.

Comment: Wont the NOT EXISTS compare NULLS?

Comment: NOT EXISTS uses two-valued logic, treating any comparison to NULL resulting in UNKNOWN as false (Explain will show "where unknown comparison will be ignored").

Comment: @dnoeth for adding MERGE Statement we will need both insert and update happening right? Here we have got only Insert. No update. Let me know if I am wrong

Comment: Merge does what you tell it to.  If you don't have a `when matched` clause, it won't do any updates.